# Vectors and boost::multiprecision::mpq_rational in Rcpp

Tags: boost, rcpp, convolution, boost-multiprecision

I am a C++ beginner hoping to find some help here.

To motivate my question, I wish to write a function that performs convolutions in C++ via either infinite precision or rational arithmetic. Since I wish to call this function from R (via **Rcpp**), I started from the following approach (which is based on [Dirk's example](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/html/convolve5__cpp_8cpp_source.html)).

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector convolve5cpp(Rcpp::NumericVector & xa,
                                 Rcpp::NumericVector & xb) {
  int n_xa = xa.size();
  int n_xb = xb.size();
  Rcpp::NumericVector xab(n_xa + n_xb - 1);
  
  Rcpp::Range r(0, n_xb-1);
  for (int i=0; i<n_xa; i++, r++) {
    xab[r] += xa[i] * xb;
  }
  return xab;
}
```

Realising I have to cast an infinite-precision rational type for my C++ variables, I next try to perform type re-casting, relying on **boost** libraries. Starting with a simple example involving scalars (shown below)...

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

mp::mpq_rational divideQ(int a, int b) {
  mp::mpq_rational c = a / b;
  return c;
}
```

I hit an error `"cannot convert type to SEXP"`.

I am lost at this point. I am aware of the **gmp** R package providing `bigq` class objects in R, but don't know if this can be leveraged to convert `mpq_rational`s into SEXP.

My questions are thus:

- How to convert a boost library rational type to a valid R object? (Ideally with `bigq` class)
- Does my reasoning make sense, or are there other approaches to this? (For example, does there already exist an implementation of `convolve5cpp` above for vectors that performs internal operations with infinite-precision?)

Many thanks!

---

**(30th Dec 2021 Update)**

Thanks to all who left helpful comments below. After some trial and error, I went ahead and tried locally editing some source files in the **gmp** library (available [here](https://github.com/cran/gmp/)).

I wrote the following function, which closely follows the example by Dirk above. I mirrored the structure of [`operator+`](https://github.com/cran/gmp/blob/master/src/bigrational.cc#L101), another function defined for addition of two `bigrational`s.

```
/**
 * \brief Return  conv( a, b )
 */
bigrational operatorCONV(const bigrational& lhs, const bigrational& rhs)
{
  /* get sizes of each vector */
  int n_xa = lhs.size();
  int n_xb = rhs.size();

  /* initialize big rational of size */
  bigrational xab(n_xa + n_xb - 1);
  
  /* fill in the entries */
  Rcpp::Range r(0, n_xb-1);
  for (int i=0; i<n_xa; i++, r++) {
    xab[r] = bigrationalR::create_bigrational(xab[r], bigrationalR::create_bigrational(lhs[i], rhs, mpq_mul), mpq_add);
  }

  /* return */
  return xab;
}
```

This didn't work. When building the package, I ran into the following errors, which look like they fall under two broad categories.

1. No member named 'size' in 'bigrational': `int n_xa = lhs.size()`.
2. Type 'const bigrational' does not provide a subscript operator: `bigrationalR::create_bigrational(lhs[i], rhs, mpq_mul)`
3. Use of undeclared identifier 'Rcpp': `Rcpp::Range r(0, n_xb-1)`
4. Use of undeclared identifier 'r': `bigrationalR::create_bigrational(xab[r],...`

Namely, 1 and 2 arise because I treat `lhs` and `rhs` as vectors of `bigrational`s; 3 and 4 arise because I use an object recognized only by **Rcpp** that wasn't included in the file.

How would one go about addressing the two broad problems? For 1 and 2, I do not understand how `add.bigq` (which calls `bigrational_add`, a function that takes in two `bigrational`s) can take in two vectors but somehow a convolution function like the above is not "flexible" like that. For 3 and 4, is there a `stdlib` alternative to `Rcpp::Range` that can be called relatively simply, or do I have to create my own object type?

Thanks again!

Comment: Briefly, it doesn't (autoMAGICally) work that way. There is no (automatic) conversion (programmed) for `mp::mpq_rational` to `SEXP`, and the compiler tells you so.  You _can_ however add those (as we say how in the Rcpp documentation) but that is not a beginner's task.

Comment: I see. Thanks for writing back, @DirkEddelbuettel. Could you point me to a simple example or where this is mentioned specifically in the documentation, so that I can try to build on it?

Comment: Most specifically the ['extending Rcpp' vignette](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-extending.pdf); the problem is also (more gingerly) discussed with some examples at the [Rcpp Gallery](https://gallery.rcpp.org).

Comment: Specific examples I've found usefule for this are [here](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-templated-wrap-and-as-for-seamingless-interfaces/) and [here](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-as-and-wrap-example/), and I've had a go at implementing custom wrappers [here](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/mapboxGeometry/blob/master/inst/include/mapboxgeometry.hpp) (among other examples)

Comment: Thanks for both your suggestions.